# Removed Settings.bundle still showing on device

Tags: xcode, settings.bundle

I removed the settings.bundle from an app I'm working on as it's no longer needed. 
However it is still being added to the device's settings when reinstalled. But the simulator doesn't add the settings bundle as expected.

***Here's what I've done so far.***

1. Deleted the settings.bundle from xcode (file only exists in the trash can).
2. Removed the settings.bundle from the Build Phases section.
3. Reset the simulator and Reinstalled app (no settings.bundle as expected)
4. Uninstalled the app from the iPhone Device and reinstalled app (**still showing settings.bundle! I don't want this!**)

Is there something I've missed or is xcode being daft??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Command+Shift+k to clean all your targets. It seems that the simulator version was re-built properly but when you build the arm version XCode doesn't see the changes you have made.